# Getting intermittent 500 0 64 on IIS logs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7.5, ahoy

I am not able to get rid of this particular `500 0 64` error which I see in my IIS logs. I keep on getting errors as shown below

> 2019-06-06 13:05:23 W3SVC10 POST **/JsEvents/Events** - 443 - HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+WOW64;+Trident/7.0;+rv:11.0)+like+Gecko **500 0 64** 0 933 655

I am using [Ahoy](https://github.com/ankane/ahoy.js) which is a javascript event tracking library in my ASP.NET MVC 5 application. This sends ajax `POST` to `JsEventsController` on every event that a user performs on the page. *This can go beyond 20k per day*. I have configured it as below:

```
ahoy.configure({
    urlPrefix: "",
    visitsUrl: '@Url.Content("~/JsEvents/Visits")',
    eventsUrl: '@Url.Content("~/JsEvents/Events")',
    page: null,
    platform: "Web",
    useBeacon: true,
    startOnReady: true,
    trackVisits: false,
    cookies: false,
    cookieDomain: null,
    headers: {},
    visitParams: {},
    withCredentials: false
});
ahoy.trackAll(false);
```

My controller which accepts the events is given below

```
[SessionState(System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly)]
public class JsEventsController : Controller
{
    private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("EventLogger");

    [HttpPost]
    public EmptyResult Visits(string visit_token, string visitor_token, string referrer, string landing_page)
    {
        logger.Trace(visit_token + " " + visitor_token + " " + referrer + " " + landing_page);
        return new EmptyResult();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public EmptyResult Events(string events_json, List<AhoyEvents> events)
    {
        if (events_json != null)
        {
            logger.Trace(events_json);
        }
        if (events != null)
        {
            logger.Trace(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(events));
        }
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

I am using NLog for `LogManager` and can provide the config if needed.

**EDIT**

I am using **Windows Server 2008 R2**.
I enabled FRT as @Lex Li advised. Please check the details below:

```
ModuleName: ManagedPipelineHandler
Notification: 128
HttpStatus: 500
HttpReason: Internal Server Error
HttpSubStatus: 0
ErrorCode: 2147943395
ConfigExceptionInfo: 
Notification: EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER
ErrorCode: The I/O operation has been aborted because of either a thread exit or an application request. (0x800703e3)
```

Comment: If there is a corresponding entry in the Windows events logs (Application) then it may well have more information.

Comment: Thanks, @AndrewMorton but there's nothing in the windows event viewer corresponding to the IIS error log entry.

Comment: When checking the event viewer, don't forget that the IIS log uses UTC time. The event time could be different. It could be an exception thrown from the logger. Perhaps it could be thrown from some other middleware and the request isn't getting to your controller. Do you mean that you're getting 20K successful requests and a few fail, or are you getting 20K 500 errors?

Comment: @ScottHannen, yes I have considered the time offset. Out of around 20k total requests in a day, some handful are failing, around 20-25.

Comment: You might use FRT to trace it down https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis but in most cases, such 500.0 comes from unhandled exceptions which you should handle properly to remedy.

Comment: @LexLi, Thank you for the advice. Please check my edit.

Comment: That's clearly an unhandled exception I think.

Comment: @LexLi, I noticed even if I put a try catch in my `Events()` method shown in question, it does not go in the catch. And anyway, handling the exception just gives us an opportunity to exit gracefully. I would like to find the root cause of this.

Comment: Posts like https://mlichtenberg.wordpress.com/2011/09/19/catching-unhandled-exceptions-in-asp-net/ might help. Your simple "try-catch" is almost useless as exceptions can be thrown elsewhere.